# Run two queries, INSERT and INSERT INTO SELECT (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO products 
                (name, price, description, stock) 
                VALUES ('$name', '$price', '$description', '$stock')");

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO products (category)
                SELECT id
                FROM categories
                WHERE category_name = '$category'");
```

These queries work fine if run individually, but how do I run them together? 
I am trying to add product data to a table and also get the category id and insert it at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can specify hardcoded values in the SELECT

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT id, 'string1', 'string2'
    FROM table2
    WHERE cond1 = val4;
```

Which will add the value if `id` and `string1` and `string2` into `table1`

In your case should be

```
INSERT INTO products (category, name, price, description, stock)
                SELECT id, '$name', '$price', '$description', '$stock'
                FROM categories
                WHERE category_name = '$category'
```